# Nuxt JS : Tailwind arbitrary values didn't work after build

Tags: vue.js, sass, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, arbitrary-values

I'm using tailwind v3 with Nuxt JS, while design the UI, I mostly use custom style `arbitrary values` of tailwind, e.g :

```
 <div class="text-[#0074C9] text-5xl font-bold leading-[60px] py-2 tracking-[-0.022em] lg:mr-[90px]">
          ...
 </div>
```

everything works fine when I run in development mode `npm run dev` but after build and run in production mode `npm run start`, all the custom styles didn't work (`text-[#0074C9], leading-[60px], tracking-[-0.022em], lg:mr-[90px]`).

is there something that I need to configure to make the custom style work in production mode?

I follow all the instruction here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nuxtjs, btw I use SASS, not CSS.

Thank you.